# Java: CRC error when using setDictionary for GZIPOutputStream's Deflater

Tags: java, checksum, crc, deflate, gzipoutputstream

I'm trying to take a stream of data from standard in, compress it one 128 byte block at a time, and then output it to standard out. (Example: "cat file.txt | java Dict | gzip -d | cmp file.txt", where file.txt just contains some ASCII characters.)

I also need to use a 32 byte dictionary taken from the end of each previous 128 byte block, for each subsequent block. (The first block uses its own first 32 bytes as its dictionary.) When I don't set the dictionary at all, the compression works fine. However, when I do set the dictionary, gzip gives me an error trying to decompress the data: "gzip: stdin: invalid compressed data--crc error".

I've tried adding/changing several parts of the code, but nothing has worked so far, and I haven't had any luck finding solutions with Google.

I've tried...

- Adding "def.reset()" before "def.setDictionary(b)" near the bottom of the code does not work.
- Only setting the dictionary for blocks after the first block does not work. (Not using a dictionary for the first block.)
- Calling updateCRC with the "input" array before or after compressor.write(input, 0, bytesRead) does not work.

I'd really appreciate any suggestions - is there anything obvious I'm missing or doing wrong?

This is what I have in my Dict.java file:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.zip.GZIPOutputStream;

public class Dict {
  protected static final int BLOCK_SIZE = 128;
  protected static final int DICT_SIZE = 32;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    InputStream stdinBytes = System.in;
    byte[] input = new byte[BLOCK_SIZE];
    byte[] dict = new byte[DICT_SIZE];
    int bytesRead = 0;

    try {
        DictGZIPOuputStream compressor = new DictGZIPOuputStream(System.out);
        bytesRead = stdinBytes.read(input, 0, BLOCK_SIZE);
        if (bytesRead >= DICT_SIZE) {
            System.arraycopy(input, 0, dict, 0, DICT_SIZE);
            compressor.setDictionary(dict);
        }

        do {
            compressor.write(input, 0, bytesRead);
            compressor.flush();

            if (bytesRead == BLOCK_SIZE) {
                System.arraycopy(input, BLOCK_SIZE-DICT_SIZE-1, dict, 0, DICT_SIZE);
                compressor.setDictionary(dict);
            }
            bytesRead = stdinBytes.read(input, 0, BLOCK_SIZE);
        } while (bytesRead > 0);

        compressor.finish();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
  }

  public static class DictGZIPOuputStream extends GZIPOutputStream {
    public DictGZIPOuputStream(OutputStream out) throws IOException {
        super(out);
    }

    public void setDictionary(byte[] b) {
        def.setDictionary(b);
    }
    public void updateCRC(byte[] input) {
        crc.update(input);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know exactly internally zlib algorithm work but based on my understanding on `DictGZIPOutputStream`, when you call write() method, after it is write, it will update its crc for that byte array. So if you call again `updateCRC()` in your code again, then thing become wrong as the crc is updated twice. Then when gzip -d is executed, as a result of previous two crc updates, gzip will complaint "invalid compressed data--crc error"

I also noticed that you did not close the compressor after it is used. When I executed the code pasted above, it gave error "gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file". So always make sure to flush method *and* close method is called in the end. With that said, I have the following,

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.zip.GZIPOutputStream;


public class Dict
{
    protected static final int BLOCK_SIZE = 128;
    protected static final int DICT_DIZE = 32;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        InputStream stdinBytes = System.in;
        byte[] input = new byte[BLOCK_SIZE];
        byte[] dict = new byte[DICT_DIZE];
        int bytesRead = 0;

        try
        {
            DictGZIPOutputStream compressor = new DictGZIPOutputStream(System.out);
            bytesRead = stdinBytes.read(input, 0, BLOCK_SIZE);

            if (bytesRead >= DICT_DIZE)
            {
                System.arraycopy(input, 0, dict, 0, DICT_DIZE);
            }

            do 
            {               
                compressor.write(input, 0, bytesRead);              

                if (bytesRead == BLOCK_SIZE)
                {
                    System.arraycopy(input, BLOCK_SIZE-1, dict, 0, DICT_DIZE);
                    compressor.setDictionary(dict);
                }

                bytesRead = stdinBytes.read(input, 0, BLOCK_SIZE);
            }
            while (bytesRead > 0);
            compressor.flush();         
            compressor.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public static class DictGZIPOutputStream extends GZIPOutputStream
    {

        public DictGZIPOutputStream(OutputStream out) throws IOException
        {
            super(out);
        }

        public void setDictionary(byte[] b)
        {
            def.setDictionary(b);
        }

        public void updateCRC(byte[] input)
        {
            crc.update(input);
        }                       
    }

}
```

The test result at the console.

```
$ cat file.txt 
hello world, how are you?1e3djw
hello world, how are you?1e3djw adfa asdfas

$ cat file.txt | java Dict | gzip -d | cmp file.txt ; echo $?
0
```

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for answering! I just saw your answer recently, and I haven't worked on this code in quite a while, so I haven't had a chance to see if it works for me yet or not. I'm assuming it does, so once I try it out myself I'll mark it as the answer.